# How Can One Test for Significance of a Particular Lag of Coefficient of ACF and PACF of Time Series Data Using R

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, arima, acf-pacf

I have this time series data presented in the `R` code below, I want to test for the significance of the first and second lag of auto-correlation and partial auto-correlation coefficient.

```
ts <- ts(c(8.6804442, 7.3541134, 8.5977826, 6.8805464, 5.1814928, 5.3389510, 5.7019002, 9.4947107, 5.6794177, -0.6920303, 2.0628462, 3.2439078, 6.1778068, 10.0745755, 7.2153141, 4.0897299, 4.9992670, 5.7246579, 5.7844691, 6.1298377, 4.5406423, 6.5713964, 5.1842466, 4.5171652, 4.1202459, 3.2100360, 4.6116722, 6.9000000), start = 1995, end = 2022, frequency = 1)
```

I understand that one can test for the significance of the whole group of lags of [image: auto-correlation (ACF)] and [image: partial auto-correlation coefficient (PACF)] as follows:

```
forecast::ggAcf(ts) + ggplot2::theme_bw()
forecast::ggPacf(ts) + ggplot2::theme_bw()
```

The reason why I need this is to specifically check if the second lag coefficient of PACF is actually significant because the `auto.arima()` function of the `forecast` package suggests that the model is `ARIMA(0,0,1)` while the interpretation of the ACF and PACF suggests `ARIMA(2,0,1)`

```
(ts_mod <- forecast::auto.arima(ts))
#Series: ts 
#ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean 

#Coefficients:
#         ma1    mean
#      0.8164  5.7382
#s.e.  0.1432  0.5931

#sigma^2 = 3.311:  log likelihood = -56
#AIC=118.01   AICc=119.01   BIC=122.01
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use simple t-tests from the following regressions.

First, to test the $k^{\text{th}}$ ACF value, fit a regression

```r
lm(Y~1+Ylag)
```

where `Ylag` is the $k^{\text{th}}$ lag you are interested in testing. Then look at the p-value for the coefficient on `Ylag`.

Second, to test the $k^{\text{th}}$ PACF value, fit an AR(k) model:

```r
Arima(Y,order=c(k,0,0))
```

And check the p-value on the coefficient on the $k^{\text{th}}$ lag.

However, I would not use statistical significance to determine variable inclusion. Instead, using AIC or BIC will typically result in a better model. You may want to set the following options in you auto.arima call:

```r
auto.arima(Y,stepwise=FALSE,approximation=FALSE,trace=TRUE)
```

- `stepwise=FALSE` will fit every possible ARIMA model under the default max p, q, and p+q constraints, not taking any shortcuts.
- `approximation=FALSE` will use the actual likelihood instead of an approximation to the likelihood when computing AIC or BIC.
- `trace=TRUE` will print the model results as it tries each model. It may take up to a few minutes (especially if it is trying seasonal models), so this is helpful as it shows you that the command is actually running and making progress.